# remove the instance while uninstall a database

Tags: sql-server

I have uninstalled the database but it's instance is still available in SQL server 2005.I want to remove that instance.Is any possibilities to remove the instance while uninstall a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you delete the database not unistall it.
in SQL Server for one instance there can be many database. i.e. one to many instance.
so there's no possibility to unistall sql server instance while deleting the database. (ofcourse unless you script it)

Uninstall the instance from control panel menu and there after.